# #1111 Invalid use of Group function in SQL: Concept?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am trying to run the below sql code that would generate the average issues for last 3 days. But, i am getting `#1111 invalid use of group function error`. No idea where i am going wrong. This stays even when i remove the group by. Please help.

```
select BookId, ChapterName, AuthorCountry,
       avg(sum(No_of_issues)) as last3dayavgissues
from library_data
where Date between (select max(Date) from library_data) and
                   (select (max(Date)-3) from library_data) 
group by BookId, ChapterName 
having (AuthorCountry='US' OR AuthorCountry='DE')) 
group by BookId, ChapterName 
order by AuthorName
into outfile 'C:/output files/abc.csv'
        fields terminated by '\t'
        lines terminated by '\n';
```

Thanks
Avi

Comment: You have group by twice.

Comment: I've tried to re-format your query but seem to have an extra `)` at the end of the `HAVING` clause - is this actually a chunk of a larger query that you've cut out (because if so, you're showing us the inner query and part of the outer query, so it's quite confusing)

Answer (score 0):

use of sum function inside avg function causes invalid use of group function error.sum function return only one value and average  of single value makes no sense.